# Symfony 3 DateTime Curl Request

Tags: php, rest, datetime, curl, symfony

I need to send with Postmal or in Curl by the console a field DateTime for my REST Api.
But When I send the value always returns to me a not valid form so it doesn't insert into my database.
If I try to change the field from DateTime to String and make a request with a string it works fine so the problem is the value sended I think

This is my Entity Birthday

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * Birthday
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="birthday")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\BirthdayRepository")
 */
class Birthday
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="birthday", type="datetime")
     */
    private $birthday;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set birthday
     *
     * @param \DateTime $birthday
     *
     * @return Birthday
     */
    public function setBirthday($birthday)
    {
        $this->birthday = $birthday;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get birthday
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getBirthday()
    {
        return $this->birthday;
    }
}
```

This is my rest api inside a controller:

```
/**
     * @Rest\Post("/users_birthday")
     */
    public function postBirthdayAction(Request $request)
    {
        $birthday = new Birthday();
        $form = $this->createForm(BirthdayType::class, $birthday);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($birthday);
            $em->flush();
            return $birthday;
            //return new JsonResponse( [$data, $status, $headers, $json])
        }

        throw new HttpException(400, "Invalid data");
    }
```

I have tried this:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -d '{
    "birthday" : "2010-10-10 10:30:11"
}
' "http://symfony-rest-api.app/users_birthday"
```

and this:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -d '{
    "birthday" : "04/21/15 20:56:16"
}
' "http://symfony-rest-api.app/users_birthday"
```

and this:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -d '{
    "birthday" : "Tue, 02 Apr 2013 10:29:13 GMT"
}
' "http://symfony-rest-api.app/users_birthday"
```

No one works.

Can someone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A field of type DateTime can be rendered in different ways. Your BirthdayType Form's birthday field must be configured as single_text type.

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType;

...

$builder->add('birthday', DateType::class, array(
    // render as a single text box
    'widget' => 'single_text',
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my last answer was incorrect.

Can you try this please:

```
curl -i -X POST http://symfony-rest-api.app/users_birthday -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -d '{"birthday" : "2010-10-10 10:30:11"}'
```

Not sure if that will work.

Comment: I get an empty error from my form, I have try with getErrors(true) but always empty

Comment: Have you checked on your Symfony server in the `var/logs` folder? And look at the content of those logs when you send the request. You can clear the logs first, and then send the request and capture any logs.